# How to show that the given algorithm generates every subset with equal probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The following question is related to my last question which i have deleted now.In my lecture notes the following recipe is given to produce a random subset of $\{1,...,n\}$.Let $n>m$

$(a)$ Choose a random permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,..,n\}$

$(b)$ Toss a fair coin $m$ times.Let $k$ be the number of successes

$(c)$ Choose a random subset $B$ of $\{\pi(m+1),...,\pi(n)\}$

Now consider the subset $$A = \begin{cases} B &  k=0 \\ \{\pi(1),...,\pi(k)\}\cup B  &\text {otherwise} \end{cases}$$

In the notes it is written that it is easy to see that above algorithm generates every subset with same probability but i cant see it.So i ask here:

> Show that the above algorithm generates every subset of $\{1,...,n\}$ with same probability

Comment: Do you mean $m < n$? Also, you begin by mentioning an equiprobable subset, but end with an equiprobable permutation. Is $A$ the output of the algorithm?

Comment: $A$ is a subset, not a permutation, so what exactly is the question?

Comment: certainly, the question makes sense now.

Comment: @HarrySmit: edited,sorry for troubling you.

Comment: "my last question which i have deleted now" Excellent... So the contributions by users to help you solve this other question are now lost? If you plan to do the same with the current question, I am not sure this is an incentive to answer...

Comment: @Did: I dint receive any answer in that question and with the help of your comment i found what i was looking for,thats why i deleted it.thanks!

Comment: Perfect, just do not complain afterwards if this has consequences...

Answer (score 0):

I will not provide a full answer here, but rather give some tips to help you make a start.

An important observation is as follows: the permutation $\pi$ can also be used to make a map of the subsets of $\{1, \dots, n\}$ of size $m$ to itself by $C \mapsto \pi(C) = \{\pi(a) | a \in C \}$. Moreover, there are exactly $m!(n-m)!$ permutations that send $C$ to $\pi(C)$ (see if you can prove this!).

This probability only depends on the size of this subset. As a result, $\{\pi(1), \dots, \pi(m)\}$ is an equiprobable subset of $\{1, \dots, n\}$ of size $m$. Moreover, $B = \{\pi(m+1), \dots, \pi(n)\}$ is an equiprobable subset of size $n - m$ (why?).

One final hint to help you gain some insight into this problem: what does the algorithm look like for $m = 0$? Do you indeed get every subset with the same probability? Try $m = 1$ afterwards. Does it still hold? Then try general $m$.